# Failed to fetch error with Git/Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I've upgraded my Jenkins instance from 1.551 to 1.625.3 (LTS), and now I'm unable to retrieve the source code from Git. I'm getting the following stacktrace/log:

```
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://jenkins@myrepo/myrepo.git

ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
FATAL: Failed to fetch from ssh://jenkins@myrepo/myrepo.git
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from ssh://jenkins@myrepo/myrepo.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:623)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:855)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:880)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.multiplescms.MultiSCM.checkout(MultiSCM.java:118)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1275)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress ssh://jenkins@myrepo/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1173)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1043)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$200(CliGitAPIImpl.java:74)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:207)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:621)
    ... 11 more
```

I can execute the same command line in Git Bash and have no issues, and I can't find any documentation on status code -1. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try upgrading the git plugin(s)?

Comment: @SteveCampbell I updated all the plugins when I upgraded Jenkins.